# OpenId Auth in Yesod

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm learning Haskell, and trying out the Yesod web framework. I'd like to set up authentication with OpenId, but I've gotten pretty confused.

There's an authOpenID authentication plugin mentioned in the book, https://www.yesodweb.com/book-1.4/authentication-and-authorization, and documented here: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-auth-1.6.10.5/docs/Yesod-Auth-OpenId.html

But that `authOpenId` function provides a widget with a form with hard-coded text about me.yahoo.com (which doesn't seem to exist anymore) and asking for a url (I guess the url of the OIDC provider?) https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-auth-1.6.10.5/docs/src/Yesod.Auth.OpenId.html#authOpenId.

So is the `authOpenId` Auth Plugin that `yesod-auth` provides more like a model I'm supposed to follow to create my own auth plugin for whatever OpenID provider I want to use? (and I guess I'd write my own routes and handlers for the authentication flow, redirecting to the provider and getting the re-redirect back?) Or am I missing the 'right' way to use the provided `authOpenId` plugin? Thanks! Any examples or clues would be most welcome!

Comment: This isn't so much an answer as a workaround - I still don't know how or whether to use Yesod-auth's built-in oauth plugin. But this library, https://github.com/freckle/yesod-auth-oauth2, works really well and was easy for me to set up. I got it working w/ Auth0, and it was pretty painless. Thanks to the freckle folks, for making it!